# Looking for a new method to create 'check-in' and 'check-out' system

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a database for a small building with a large number of HDDs and the system I have made so far works exactly as my employer desires it to.

My current problem is with some VBA coding using macros to sign in and sign out each hard drive, the hard drives have a row each with a 'check in' and 'check out' button at the end. At current moment the coding works for both of these buttons but I have to write out the code for every single button both 'check in' and 'check out'.

Is there a way to convert the location of the button into a string which would then add itself into the coding and I can put in some sort of array that will auto locate the output of each button for me?

[image: The coding that handles the button's event.]

The macro is a simple `.Show` statement.
My excel sheet is illustrated below. Most of the current cells are programmed with formulas as this system needs to be fairly automated for the less skilled computer users.

[image: Excel visuals, explaining cell values.]

**Edit:**
[image: Before I used button to 'check-in' HDD.]

After clicking the button my initials are added to the end of current time/date. This needs to happen for many buttons all results being in different cells.

[image: Output following button.]

Comment: What do you mean by "location of the button"? What does your desired output look like?

Comment: E3:E7 and F3:F7 both have the correct output; the date/time and initials that are inputted in the VBA UserInputForm. I shall upload another image to help you understand. :)

P.s Thanks for the edit; I have just signed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to avoid using a button, and instead override the SelectionChanged event handler for the worksheet. Change the buttons to formatted cells, which when clicked will perform the action you desire.

First, configure your UserForm to return a value. One way to do this is by placing the following code into the code-behind for the UserForm:

```
Public Property Get Initials() As String
  Initials = txtInitials.Text
End Property

Public Property Let Initials(ByVal sInitials As String)
  txtInitials.Text = sInitials
End Property

Private Sub btnOk_Click()
  Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Next, add the following code to `Sheet1`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim sInitials As String
  Dim sDate As String
  Dim sTime As String
  Dim frmInitials As InitialsForm

  If Target.Column = 13 Then
    Set frmInitials = New InitialsForm
    frmInitials.Show

    sInitials = frmInitials.Initials

    Unload frmInitials

    sDate = Date
    sTime = Time
    Cells(Target.Row, 6).Value = sDate + " / " + sTime + " " + sInitials
  End If
End Sub
```

When the user clicks on a cell in column 13 (M - "Check Out"), a userform will be displayed asking for the user's initials. Once they have entered them and pressed the OK button, the initials will be added to the end of the timestamp and inserted into column 6 (F) of the same row.

Comment: I am not seeing how this is a plausable answer as I must stick to including simplicity and peoples initials; the system must retain it's automatic behaviours...The altering of a cell could cause errors in the system if the user enters the wrong information hence why I have had to stick to a button. (Not meant to sound as harsh as I wrote it.) :P

Comment: What is the difference? Regardless of whether it was triggered by a button click or SelectionChange event, essentially the same code is being executed. Perhaps I'm not understanding your question. My take on your question is that you are trying to locate each button in the sheet and update the corresponding row after it is pressed and the user enters their initials. The code above will do just that, without needing to use buttons. Am I incorrect in this assessment?

Comment: That is what I need, maybe I am inputting your code incorrectly but won't I just have to repeat your code for each button? Just like I have mine?

Comment: The answer to that last question is a qualified No. Assuming all of your "Check Out" buttons are in the same column (i.e. all in column M), and assuming that each button outputs the resulting string (`LDate + " / " + LTime + " " + txt`) to the same column (i.e. column F) of whichever row the button is in, then you can add the code above to your worksheet and it will automatically "wire up" every button. You can add as many "buttons" as you need by simply adding another row, and the above code will automatically respond to that "button" being clicked.

Comment: Thank you for explaining Brett! That helps a lot. The only thing I am not understanding is your reference to formatting the cells as spoken of here "Change the buttons to formatted cells, which when clicked will perform the action you desire." How do I go about setting this up?

Comment: The code works at the minute but I am unaware of how to edit the button and make it into a button that will input the txt variable?

Comment: Take a look at the updated code. I recognized that you are using a UserForm for receiving input, and added that to the code. You may need to modify the variable and form names, but otherwise the code should do what you are asking.